# Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to fetch a request from urllib3 and my code works. However, few websites like https://hackershala.com and etc which uses different TLS version are not being able to be fetched.
I tried changing useragent, but it didn't work for obvious reasons.

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hackershala.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

My code is

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = input("Website URL: ")
r = http.request("GET", url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
})
rp = r.status
print(rp)
```

Comment: Your code is working fine as I tested with `200` response, what about your internet?

Comment: Have you tried using the above URL mentioned? @AdamStrauss

Comment: Yes I tried both i.e. hackershala.com and https://hackershala.com

Comment: @AdamStrauss Any way to fix it on my PC? That error is strange...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add this line to configure your urllib3

```
import requests
import urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
```